# Divide text in different groups using regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract some data using regex. I'm currently using python and the data can be like this:

```
text [text1 & text2]
text [text1]
text [text2]
text
```

There is a "text" value (can be one, or more words) and can be followed by `[]` or no. In case `[]` exists, the text inside can be two words separated by `&` or only one of them (at the moment exists only two possible words but I think is better to get the words by separator instead of matching the exact word)

So my goal is to get the data in two different groups:

- Group1: text
- Group2: [text1, text2] (if exists)

My regex is:

```
(^([^\[])+)(.+?(?=&|\]))?(.+?(?=\]))?
```

I've tried this using [findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) which I think fits better with the result I want:

```py
regex = "(^([^\[])+)(.+?(?=&|\]))?(.+?(?=\]))?"
result = re.findall(regex,text)
```

But it returns:

```
[('text ', ' ', '[text1 ', '& text2')]
```

And I want, something like:

```py
[('text'), ('text1', 'text2')]
```

I've tried in [this playground](https://regex101.com/r/MIVnRA/1)

How can I improve my regex pattern?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
(?x)            # Extended (whitespace and comments are ignored)
([^[]+)         # Group 1: 1 or more non-'[' characters
(?:             # Start of a non-capturing group 1
   \s*          # Match optional whitespace
   \[           # Match '['
   ([^&\]]+)    # Group 2: 1 or more non- '&' or ']' characters
   (?:          # Start of a non-capturing group 2
      \s*       # Match optional whitespace
      &         # Match '&'
      \s*       # Match optional whitespace
      ([^\]]+)  # Capture group 3: 1 or more non-']' characters
      \s*       # Match optional whitespace
   )*           # End of optional non-capturing group 2
   ]            # Match ']'
)*              # End of optional non-capturing group 1
```

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/MdjQYq/1)

```py
import re

tests = [
    'text [text1 & text2]',
    'text [text1]',
    'text [text2]',
    'text'
]

regex = r"""(?x)# Extended (whitespace and comments are ignored)
([^[]+)         # Group 1: 1 or more non-'[' characters
(?:             # Start of a non-capturing group 1
   \s*          # Match optional whitespace
   \[           # Match '['
   ([^&\]]+)    # Group 2: 1 or more non- '&' or ']' characters
   (?:          # Start of a non-capturing group 2
      \s*       # Match optional whitespace
      &         # Match '&'
      \s*       # Match optional whitespace
      ([^\]]+)  # Capture group 3: 1 or more non-']' characters
      \s*       # Match optional whitespace
   )*           # End of optional non-capturing group 2
   ]            # Match ']'
)*              # End of optional non-capturing group 1
"""
for test in tests:
    # Here I am doing a fullmatch, but you can do a search to be more lenient:
    m = re.fullmatch(regex, test)
    if m:
        results = m[1], m[2], m[3]
        print(test, '->', results)
```

Prints:

```None
text [text1 & text2] -> ('text ', 'text1 ', 'text2')
text [text1] -> ('text ', 'text1', None)
text [text2] -> ('text ', 'text2', None)
text -> ('text', None, None)
```

You can, of course, group the results any way you want, such as:

```py
results = (m[1], (m[2] or '' , m[3] or ''))
```

Prints:

```None
text [text1 & text2] -> ('text ', ('text1 ', 'text2'))
text [text1] -> ('text ', ('text1', ''))
text [text2] -> ('text ', ('text2', ''))
text -> ('text', ('', ''))
```

**Update**

This regex will do a better job of automatically trimming whitespace if you know there is always whitespace before the '[' and '&' characters:

```
(?x)            # Extended (whitespace and comments are ignored)
([^[]+)         # Group 1: 1 or more non-'[' characters
(?:             # Start of a non-capturing group 1
   \s+          # Match whitespace
   \[           # Match '['
   ([^&\]]+)    # Group 2: 1 or more non- '&' or ']' characters
   (?:          # Start of a non-capturing group 2
      \s+       # Match whitespace
      &         # Match '&'
      \s*       # Match optional whitespace
      ([^\]]+)  # Capture group 3: 1 or more non-']' characters
      \s*       # Match optional whitespace
   )*           # End of optional non-capturing group 2
   ]            # Match ']'
)*              # End of optional non-capturing group 1
```

Code:

```py
import re

tests = [
    'text [text1 & text2]',
    'text [text1]',
    'text [text2]',
    'text'
]

regex = r"""(?x)# Extended (whitespace and comments are ignored)
([^[]+)         # Group 1: 1 or more non-'[' characters
(?:             # Start of a non-capturing group 1
   \s+          # Match whitespace
   \[           # Match '['
   ([^&\]]+)    # Group 2: 1 or more non- '&' or ']' characters
   (?:          # Start of a non-capturing group 2
      \s+       # Match whitespace
      &         # Match '&'
      \s*       # Match optional whitespace
      ([^\]]+)  # Capture group 3: 1 or more non-']' characters
      \s*       # Match optional whitespace
   )*           # End of optional non-capturing group 2
   ]            # Match ']'
)*              # End of optional non-capturing group 1
"""
for test in tests:
    # Here I am doing a fullmatch, but you can do a search to be more lenient:
    m = re.fullmatch(regex, test)
    if m:
        results = (m[1], (m[2] or '' , m[3] or ''))
        print(test, '->', results)
```

Prints:

```None
text [text1] -> ('text', ('text1', ''))
text [text2] -> ('text', ('text2', ''))
text -> ('text', ('', ''))
```

Comment: See the updated answer for a possibly improved regex.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with python, but I don't think it's possible to get more than one value from one group in a regular expression, so my guess is that you'd have to use something like this

```
(\w+)(?: \[(.*)\])?
```

> Which will give you one or two groups
>
> ```
> [('text'), ('text1 & text2')]
> [('text'), ('text1')]
> [('text'), ('text2')]
> [('text')]
> ```

And then if the second group exists, use a second regular expression to get each individual value from it.

You can have a look here: https://regex101.com/r/DxF5p1/1

Comment: Thanks for your time. Into [findAll](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) documentation an example return `[('width', '20'), ('height', '10')]`. Which is two values for each group, so I thought it was possible. Also your regex when `text` are two eords return me the second word in the second group: text `two words [text1 & text2]` returns  `[('two', ''), ('words', 'text1 & text2')]`

Comment: As I said, I'm not familiar with python, so maybe it's possible to do exactly what you want.  You may also be confusing matches with groups, for that I'd recommend having a look at the "MATCH INFORMATION" section of the link I shared.